# nvd3 Barchart show values on chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

In nvd3 Barchart, Is there a way to show values on top of each bars?

I tried .showValues(true) and i get "***error showValues() not a function***"

```
nv.models.multiBarChart()
.showValues(true)
```

Comment: the api says that http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#multiBarChart doesn't have that function.

Comment: Can use a discreteBarChart?